# Saving Alamofire request data into a variable

Tags: swift, request, alamofire

I'm having troubles with getting password salt from my VM server via **Alamofire**. I'm making a request to server and it should return me salt, so I can salt my password, hash it and send it back to server.

The problem is that I do not understand how to save the salt, that Alamofire receives, into a variable, so I can just add it to password and hash it like that:

```
let salted_password = user_password + salt
let hash = salted_password.sha1()
```

Where `user_password` is what the user entered into password field and `salt` is what I got from Alamofire salt request.

Here is my code:

```
func getSalt(completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<String>, Error?) -> Void) {

        Alamofire.request("http://192.168.0.201/salt", method: .post, parameters: salt_parameters).responseString { response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            completionHandler(response as DataResponse<String>, nil)
        case .failure(let error):
            completionHandler("Failure", error)
            }
        }
    }

    let salt = getSalt { response, responseError in

        return response.result.value!
    }
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and '()'.
```

So is it possible to save a request value into a variable? What should I do?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: What is the return value of `getSalt()`? It seems you are trying to combine a `String` with the outcome of that function which you cannot (as you've discovered the hard way :))

Comment: what you should do is something like this instead. `var salt: String?; getSalt { response, responseError in salt = response.result.value; }`

Comment: @ZonilyJame Thanks a lot, it works!

Comment: @ОлегЗахаров I'll add an answer, could you accept it :)

Comment: Upvote the comment too if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is because of how you implemented your `completion block`

**For example:**

```
func someAsynchronousCall(a: Int, b: Int, @escaping block: (_ result: Int) -> Void) {
    ... some code here
    ... { 
        // let's just say some async call was done and this code is called after the call was done
        block(a + b)
    }
}
```

To use this code it would look like this:

```
var answer: Int = 0
someAsynchronousCall(100, b: 200) { result in // the `result` is like what you're returning to the user since API calls need to be called asynchronously you do it like this rather than creating a function that has a default return type.
    answer = result
    print(answer)
}
print(answer)
```

The print would look like this

```
0
300
```

Since we declared answer as `0` it printed that first since the async call wasn't done yet, after the async call was done (usually a few milliseconds after) it then printed `300`

So all in all your code should look something like this

```
var salt: String?
getSalt { response, responseError in 
    salt = response.result.value 
}
```